# Deduplicate CSS rule in class and media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I currently have a CSS with rules which are duplicates in both `.small` and the media query for `#a`, because I want the same behaviour when browser width is smaller than 600px and when a button is clicked.

In my real case, the rules are very long, and I would like to avoid to duplicate them. **How to deduplicate such a CSS?**

```js
$('#b').click(function(){ $('#a').addClass('small'); });
```

```css
#a { background-color: green; }
.small { background-color: yellow !important; /* many other rules */ }

@media (max-width: 600px) { 
    #a { background-color: yellow !important; /* many other rules */ }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Hello</div>
<input id="b" type="button" value="Change" />
```

Comment: You should try to avoid styling ID's and for the most part, only style classes. In addition, the use of `!important` is sloppy, and just means the stylesheet is not written logically. Your best bet might be going through and re-doing your entire stylesheet.

Comment: @JROB Thanks for the tip, but I don't see how replacing `<div id="a">` by  `<div class="a">` and  `#a { ... }` by `.a { ... }` would change anything about the rule duplication problem...

Comment: @JROB can you explain what you had in mind in order to solve the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this in pure CSS, this is one of the things you can solve with precompilers like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) where you can inject CSS rules anywhere you want with variables or [mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide) for example

Comment: Thanks, but indeed I wanted to achieve this in pure CSS, with no precompiler.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of Javascript solution to your problem.

```
window.onresize = function(event){
 if(window.innerWidth < 600px){
  // add the class to the element
 }else{
 // remove the class
 }
}
```

I don't think you can achive what you want in any other way without using precompiler.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a CSS pre-processor to do this.

Otherwise you'd have to use jQuery to toggle some other class based on viewport width or assign the `.small` styles to `#a` as well, then make a media query to undo it all when you don't want it to look like that.

Comment: Interesting, can you precise your 2nd solution?